# How to use the loop to import multiple js files and export all those js files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've revised the question to help people understand what I'm looking for help with.
I have a directory tree as follows:

```
--action
  --a.js
  --b.js
  --c.js
  --d.js
--data
  --list.js
--export
  --exp.js
```

Files js: a, b, c, d all have 1 function as follows:

```
module.export = {
  "test": function name () {
    //do something
  }
}
```

In the list.js file. I have an array like this.

```
const list = [ 'a', 'b' ];
```

At the exp.js file, I want to export all js files in the action directory through an array in the list.js

> Desired: use the loop to import multiple js files and export all those
> js files.

Thank you everyone for reading and helping.

Comment: I'd recommend against doing something like this because you will probably not be able to do something like this using the ESM module syntax which is the future of the Javascript language.  Exports must be statically  declared in ESM modules.  I'd suggest pursuing a different design that doesn't lock you into CommonJS modules forever.

Comment: Why does your `file export.js` export a function? How do you plan to import and use it? What do the action modules export, and how do you want to use/access those?

Comment: My purpose was to import multiple js files but to perform the for loop so I put it in a function.

Comment: Because the value of the list array is the name of the js files that I want to require

Answer (score 1):

[V8](https://v8.dev/) provides you with an option called [Dynamic Import](https://v8.dev/features/dynamic-import) which helps you to import file dynamically. dynamic import loads your module and returns a module object that contains all its exports. In order to access the `default` export use the `default` property of the module object.

```js
const moduleA = await import ('./moduleA');
moduleA.default();

// OR

const { default: moduleA } = await import ('./moduleA');
moduleA();
```

Comment: because I want to require all files to match the value of the array, should I think this is not possible.

Comment: if you want you can loop over your list. this is just a way in which you can import a module dynamically. @Hidden

Comment: I'm not very good at js, so can you explain it more clearly for me? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can do this with plain require, using a dynamic import just makes it more complicated. That said, this is a correct answer and shouldn't have been downvoted. I +1'd you back to zero